# WebMethod not getting called from Ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to execute the below code for AutoComplete, but when I debug/execute the code. I noticed its not hitting my web method.

my ASPX Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SearchText();
    });  
    function SearchText() {
        $('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var param = { searchStr: $('#TextBox1').val() };
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetCountry",
                    // data: "{searchStr:JSON.stringify('u')}",
                    data: "{searchStr: 'xx'}",
                    //data: JSON.stringify(param),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);

                    },
                    error: function (msg, text) {
                        alert(msg);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

C# code behind code ---- simply hard coded the values for testing purpose

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true,    ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] 

public static string[] GetCountry(string searchStr)
{
   List<string> listCt = new List<string>();
   listCt.Add("UnitedStates");
   listCt.Add("UnitedKingdom");
   listCt.Add("UnitedArab");
   listCt.Add("UnitedNations");
   return listCt.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: hmmm why using aspx page? I have already done something like that in the past, but with .asmx file.

Comment: it could be possible in either way,have tried both ; yet not fruitful.....trying to figure out the error......Any help  appreciated

Comment: I think you can't use single quote "{searchStr: 'xx'}" that way in a json string.

Comment: ok I think I see what is the problem. You use $.ajax to POST data, but the method the method respond only to Get request. Remove UseHttpGet = true.